# How to stop auto-refreshing of SBT modules upon opening project in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

We have several Play 2 applications and modules and I'm having trouble integrating IntelliJ IDEA 13 into my development process. I have an empty project based on the common parent of the apps and I have imported each app as a module using the import existing SBT project option.

My problem is that every time I launch the project, IntelliJ causes SBT to completely rebuild all 9 modules at the same time. Since they all depend on one `sbt.lock` file being available, it's usually the case that 8 of the apps are waiting at any one time, and it takes ~15 minutes for the refreshing to finish. As it spawns an sbt process for each module, my VM's 5GB of RAM and 5GB of swap space are entirely filled, causing further slowdown.

This is completely unacceptable. I'm going back to Eclipse if I can't solve this problem, event if IntelliJ IDEA is better suited to my development otherwise. How can I disable these automatic rebuilds at startup, or at least serialize them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is an open request: [SCL-7061 Disable SBT project refreshing](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7061) You may want to try the [IDEA 14 Preview release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) (and the updated Scala Plug-in) to see if the issue is resolved or better there. I know there has been some improvements to Scala and SBT in IDEA 14. If it works for you, you can switch to using the [IDEA 14 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP) builds until it is released later this year.

Comment: Thanks for that. Since there appears to be no fix for IntelliJ IDEA 13, I'm marking this as the accepted answer.