# How to stop Intellij from automatically running SBT

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I imported an SBT project into into Intellij 13.1.

Whenever I change build.sbt, plugins.sbt, etc., Intellij reruns SBT.

Sometime that is nice, but when I do lot of stuff in the console, and after frequent changes, I have to wait because my IDE locks SBT from running (and SBT is sloooow).

Anyway, can I turn off the automatic SBT run in Intellij. I would prefer to do it myself, from the provided SBT window.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IntelliJ 14.1 now allows you to adjust SBT settings after importing projects.

File > Settings > Build > Build Tools > SBT
(Or click the settings button on the SBT projects panel.)

Uncheck "auto-import".

[image]

This is the user-friendly equivalent of david.perez's answer.

Comment: They seemingly dropped the support for that in IDEA-2017.1. That's a pity, it was very useful. You could refresh the structure when you've really done your iteration. And a working project didn't break unless you did it yourself.

Answer (score 25):

I would leave the autoimport checkbox unchecked when importing a SBT project.

In this way, it doesn't refresh automatically, it must be done by hand.

In order to change it, after it has been imported, you can edit by hand the `.idea/sbt.xml file`:

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="ScalaSbtSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <SbtProjectSettings>
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="jdk" value="1.7" />
        <option name="resolveClassifiers" value="true" />
        <option name="useAutoImport" value="true" />
      </SbtProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

and change the `useAutoImport` setting.
If necessary, restart IDEA.

*UPDATE*: Also in the settings page, search for SBT, and there you can enable or disable auto-import of SBT files.

When doing heavy work on a .sbt file, I disable auto-import.

Comment: Is resolveClassifiers responsible for downloading sources and docs for dependencies?

Comment: Awesome! For some reason I had difficulty finding that setting.

Answer (score 18):

In IntelliJ 2017.1 and later, you open the `SBT projects` window on the right sidebar, right-click on the project name, and uncheck the `Auto-import` option

Answer (score 2):

In Community 2020.2 (on MacOS, but it probably doesn't change), the path is Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Reload project after changes in build scripts. Sadly, it appears to only be settable for the current project, not globally.

[image: Intellij IDEA 2020.2 Build Tools Settings Window]

Comment: Same for 2021.1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely solve it, but I've found that removing all `target/` directories from the IntelliJ project helps a lot and greatly reduces waiting on Ivy locks.

For all `target/` directories, right click, Mark Directory As, Excluded. If you're using sbt sub-projects, you'll have multiple of these (otherwise, just one).

Source: https://twitter.com/andstuff/status/516987670170697728

Related issue: [How to stop auto-refreshing of SBT modules upon opening project in IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122281/how-to-stop-auto-refreshing-of-sbt-modules-upon-opening-project-in-idea), suggests upgrading to IDEA 14 Preview releases.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers have clear instructions for Mac.

On Mac the workflow is IntellJ IDEA > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > SBT > Use Auto-Import

[image: Mac Version 16 SBT]

Comment: ... and it's already outdated. No such setting as of 2017.1 as far as I see.

Comment: I do see the settings generally, but there is no "Use auto-import" checkbox in it. For the 2017.01 IDE version that I've recently upgraded to. Do you have 2017.01 ?

Comment: The `.idea/sbt.xml` has a `<option name="useOurOwnAutoImport" value="true" />` entry in it now, for projects imported from sbt file from scratch. I guess this is it.

Comment: I have 2016.3.5 apparently.